# How to get the face book logging authentication for a user using .net framework

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, facebook

I am trying to implement a windows desktop chat application for windows 7 using C# .net 4.0 . I still could not find a way to get the authentication for a given user and a password. Can anyone have an idea to perform this? Please help

Comment: This seems like the sort of question that could be easily answered by a simple google search.  If you're having a particular problem, please post more clearly.  If you're looking for good places to get started, read Facebook's documentation.

Comment: No downvote. Have you searched the Facebook official docs..?

Comment: Okay you did not get my question sir. I am trying ti implement a desktop application and you did a wrong thing . Why don't you have a Google search and look rather than downgrading?

Comment: @Kalanamith: Can't you yourself do a Google search..?

Comment: @Kalanamith People share what they know, here. No one is obliged to do a search for you. Try to implement the feature yourself & if you get stuck somewhere post the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume something like this is what you were looking for: [4th Google result](http://codesamplez.com/programming/facebook-api-access-token-using-c-sharp)

Comment: okay i have gone through it.  though um new to this technology um looking for a simple approach